# snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux, audio

Hi I use Linux for long time and I have one problem I check on different distribution found nothing
My laptop sound work perfectly fine but every time I boot my system I get two messages on my gnome log

1. snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: no codecs found!
2. A empty message sender by system

Now I'm in garuda linux It will makes me happy if some one fix it because it so annoying

Answer (score 0):

Try installing sof-audio-pci using `sudo pacman -Sy sof-audio-pci`

This will install some audio codecs.

This command is for Arch Linux but it should work on Garuda Linux since it is based on Arch.

Comment: There isn't any sof-audio-pci even in aur do you mean sof-firmware if yes it's installed by default